# ¿Como crear un Automata Finito Determinista para entradas de RUT?

Tags: java, automatafinito

Para un trabajo de la Universidad el profesor propuso el siguiente problema:

**Asuma que necesita procesar un documento en el se hacen referencia o aparecen RUTs de personas naturales o jurìdicas. El problema es que estos RUTs estàn escritos de diferentes formas.**

**Por ejemplo, 9911321-K o 09901321K o 09911321k o 09911321-k o 09.911.321k o 9.911.321k o 9.911.321K o 09.911.321-K.**

**Como puede ver hay muchas formas diferentes en las que puede aparece un RUT dentro del documento. Usted puede imaginar otras posiblidades de escribir el RUT. Esta parte de la tarea consiste en:**

**(a) Diseñe un AFD M que reconozca si un string dado w es un RUT.**

**(b) Implemente en su lenguaje de programaci´on favorito el AFD M.**

**(c) Implemente una aplicacion (tambien en su lenguaje favorito) que a partir de un documento de entrada (doc.tex) reconozca y muestre en la salida standar (pantalla) los posibles RUTs que se encuantran en el documento. Asuma que las palabras en el documento vienen separadas por espacios. Un ejemplo de un documento es el siguiente.**

**Este es un documento que tiene varios
RUTs. Por ejemplo, el Rut 10.123.456-7
y tambien el 8889566K ....etc.**

En cuanto al programa no tengo problemas, el problema esta en crear el AFD que pueda consumir las diferenetes formas de escribir un RUT.
[image: AFD que elabore]

Puede consumir diferentes rut como:

09.123.123-k

9.123.123-k

09123123-k

*9123123-k*

*9123123k*

Las 2 ultimas son las que mi AFD no puede consumuir.
Alguien tiene una solucion a esto?
Debe de ser una soluciòn que se pueda aplicar a java.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Favor aclarar, tu pregunta es sobre el AFD, el que ya diagramaste? o esperas una solución implementable con JAVA para definir y evaluar basado en ese AFD dadas las entradas de texto????. si tienes código fuente para esto, deberías incluirlo, y el caso de la prueba de los últimos para ver las transiciones

Comment: Gracias por le interes, el problema era que el AFD que desarrolle no abarcaba a todos los casos posibles

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo solo:

Primero hay que desarrollar lo mas censillo que es una expresion regular, que en este caso es:

(d|dd)(.d|d)dd(.d|d)dd(-k|k|-d|d)

donde d es un digito, un numero entre el 0 y el 9.

Luego se desarrolla un AFND (automata finito no determinista) utilizando el metodo de Thompson, quedando algo asi:

[image: AFND]

Y finalmente una conversion de AFND a AFD quedando lo siguiente:

[image: AFD]

Solamente me falta aplicarlo a mi programa JAVA y ya estaria listo.

Comment: El estado q21 es final también? puede terminar en dígito sin la k final? mismo caso para q20 y q17

Comment: q21 si es final, según los rut chilenos, el digito verificador puede ser un nuemero del 0 al 9 o ser k.